# Querying multiple tables two being junction tables

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a sql query that queries records from multiple tables which involved junction tables. The Userprofile table has relationship with Role and team table and one to one relationship with TimeZone table.

I am trying to achieve a query that will pull records from UserProfile table as well relevant records from Role , team and timezone table. I have tried to write a query and it is getting overly complex. Could somebody verify my query and tell me the right way to do it

The tables are as follows

**UserProfile table**

```
  [EmployeeID]
  [Forename]
  [Surname]
  [PreferredName]
  [DefaultLanguageCode]
  [DefaultCountryCode]
  [TimeZoneID]
  [Domain]
  [NetworkID]
```

**Team table**

```
   [TeamID]
   [CountryCode]
   [TeamName]
   [TeamDescription]
```

**UserTeamLinkTable**

```
  [UserProfileTeamLinkID]
  [TeamID]
  [UserProfileID]
  [isDefault]
  [isActive]
```

**UserRole Table**

```
   [RoleID]
   [RoleDescription]
   [isActive]
```

**UserRoleLink Table**

```
[UserProfileRoleLinkID]
   [RoleID]
   [UserProfileID]
   [isActive]
```

**TimeZone table**

```
  [TimeZoneID]
  [TimeZoneCode]
  [TimeZone]
  [TimeZoneName]
```

**Query**

```
select 

    userprofile.[UserProfileID]
   ,userprofile.[EmployeeID]
   ,userprofile.[Forename]
   ,userprofile.[Surname]
   ,userprofile.[PreferredName]
   ,userprofile.[DefaultCountryCode]
   ,userprofile.[DefaultLanguageCode]
   ,userprofile.[TimeZoneID]
   ,userprofile.TeamID
   ,userprofile.TeamName
   ,userprofile.[Domain]
   ,userprofile.[NetworkID]
   ,userprofile.[EmailAddress]
   ,userprofile.[CreatedDate]
   ,userprofile.[CreatedBy]
   ,userprofile.[ModifiedDate]
   ,userprofile.[ModifiedBy]

 from TimeZone tz inner join 
(
select 
   up.[UserProfileID]
   ,up.[EmployeeID]
   ,up.[Forename]
   ,up.[Surname]
   ,up.[PreferredName]
   ,up.[DefaultCountryCode]
   ,up.[DefaultLanguageCode]
   ,up.[TimeZoneID]
   ,te.TeamID
   ,te.TeamName
   ,up.[Domain]
   ,up.[NetworkID]
   ,up.[EmailAddress]
   ,up.[CreatedDate]
   ,up.[CreatedBy]
   ,up.[ModifiedDate]
   ,up.[ModifiedBy]


from [dbo].[UserProfileTeamLink] upt
inner join UserProfile up on up.UserProfileID = upt.UserProfileID
inner join Team te on te.TeamID = upt.TeamID ) userprofile  on tz.TimeZoneID = userprofile.TimeZoneID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to say without knowing what the data looks like or what the desired output looks like. You could join all of the tables without using sub queries if you are expecting multiple rows per user because of those many to many relationships.

```
select 
    up.[UserProfileID]
   ,up.[EmployeeID]
   ,up.[Forename]
   ,up.[Surname]
   ,up.[PreferredName]
   ,up.[DefaultCountryCode]
   ,up.[DefaultLanguageCode]
   ,up.[TimeZoneID]
   ,tz.TimeZone
   ,te.TeamID
   ,te.TeamName
   ,up.[Domain]
   ,up.[NetworkID]
   ,up.[EmailAddress]
   ,up.[CreatedDate]
   ,up.[CreatedBy]
   ,up.[ModifiedDate]
   ,up.[ModifiedBy]
   ,ur.RoleDescription
from UserProfile up 
  inner join TimeZone tz 
    on tz.TimeZoneID = up.TimeZoneID
  inner join UserProfileTeamLink upt
    on upt.UserProfileID = upt.UserProfileID
  --and upt.isDefault = 1 /* default team only? */
  --and upt.isActive = 1  /* active team only? */
  inner join Team te 
    on te.TeamID = upt.TeamID
  inner join UserProfileRoleLink upr /* left join if users might not have a role*/
    on up.UserProfileID = upr.UserProfileId
  --and upr.isActive = 1  /* active role only? */
  inner join UserRole ur /* left join if users might not have a role*/
    on upr.RoleId = ur.RoleId
```